# drawing Opengl texture several times

Tags: c++, opengl

I initialize texture 
`(glGenTexture, glBindTexture, glTexImage1D)` and draw it later `(glBindTexture, glTexSubImage1D, glDrawArrays())`, everything works well. But sometimes texture data wasn't changed and I want to redraw same texture without expensive `glTexSubImage1D` call. How can I do that?

Comment: Please add some code that shows what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Store the texture handle (what you get from `glGenTextures` and what you pass to `glBindTexture`).  This is what represents the texture when communicating with OpenGL.  When you want to use this texture again later, call `glBindTexture` with this handle and then render your geometry.  It will reuse the texture data that you last uploaded with `glTexImage1D` or `glTexSubImage1D`.

If you weren't doing that already, then you should also remember to `glDeleteTextures` your texture handle when you no longer need it.